# Is it possible to serialize an Object, put it in a Room database, and then deserialize it when needed?

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-room

I have a complex Java object that will take me weeks of refactoring to get it to be stored following the guide here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships

I have multiple "A"s having a map of "B to double" and each "B" has multiple maps of "double to double". These classes were not made for a database, but to be saved to a file via serialization. It is deeply entrenched into my project. Due to an increase in the amount of memory the objects take due to the multiple maps of "double to double", I need a way to store the maps on disk and fetch when needed.

Is it possible to serialize map "B to double" and maps "double to double", put them in a Room database as a blob field of an entity "A", and store it all in a database?

The goal is to take map "B to double" and the maps of "double to double" from an "A" when needed. Is this possible or do I need to rewrite my classes as described in the page above?

Comment: Not a good idea to store big data inside a database. You must store a path link in your database which point to your data that you save as file.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot more sense.